# Is it possible to provide AWS console access using OpenId Federation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook-graph-api, openid, amazon-iam

I am trying to allow users to login to AWS console using Facebook account. So far I am pretty sure assuming role with web identity allows facebook app users to access my AWS resources. But, Is it possible to explicitly sign-in to AWS Console using Web Identity?

Comment: yes you can it here sharing official documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc.html